# Click Event Sender in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, events, gridview, contextmenu

I am desinging a wpf application. I code a grid(which has 35 textblocks)-wide context menu. when I click mouse's right button I need to learn on which textblock I clicked. But click event gives centext menu as a sender. How can I reach on which textblock the user click right mouse button?

My XAML code---------------------------------------------------------------:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Hafta İçi" x:Name="btnWeekDay" Click="btnWeekDay_Click" />
                <MenuItem Header="Cuma" x:Name="btnFriday" Click="btnFriday_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Cumartesi" x:Name="btnSaturday" Click="btnSaturday_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Pazar" x:Name="btnSunday" Click="btnSunday_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="İdari İzin" x:Name="btnAdminLeave" Click="btnAdminLeave_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Bayram/Tatil" x:Name="btnHoliday" Click="btnHoliday_Click" a/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
```

My C# code-------------:

```
private void btnWeekDay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sender + e.Source.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Did you check the MouseButtonEventArgs' `OriginalSource` property?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: My event is  mouse right button click so I can't reach mousebuttoneventargs.

Comment: The code you posted is showing you handling `Click`, not `MouseRightButtonDown`. There is also no `TextBlock` to be seen anywhere in your code. Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the issue. Note that with the `ContextMenu` attached to the `Grid`, it's the `Grid` handling the mouse event that opens the context menu. You might want to consider styling your grid items so that each of them actually owns a context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. 
1. I moved contextmenu from grid to the textblocks.
2. I fired contextmenuopening event and catch the texblock on which I click rght mouse button.

Here is the xaml code.

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="txtBlockStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="borderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGreen"/>
        </Style>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="txtBlockContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Hafta İçi" x:Name="btnWeekDay" Click="btnWeekDay_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Cuma" x:Name="btnFriday" Click="btnFriday_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Cumartesi" x:Name="btnSaturday" Click="btnSaturday_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Pazar" x:Name="btnSunday" Click="btnSunday_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="İdari İzin" x:Name="btnAdminLeave" Click="btnAdminLeave_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Bayram/Tatil" x:Name="btnHoliday" Click="btnHoliday_Click" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Page.Resources>
.....
    <Border Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" >
                <TextBlock x:Name="txtDate1"  ContextMenuOpening="CustomContextMenuOpening" ContextMenu="{StaticResource ResourceKey=txtBlockContextMenu}"></TextBlock>
            </Border>
```

Here is code behind.

```
TextBlock targetTextBlock;

private void CustomContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
        {
            targetTextBlock = (TextBlock)sender;
        }
```